# if.... else condition of my code in only working on codeblocks, codeforces is says wrong ans

Tags: c, if-statement, conditional-statements

here is the code, conditions aren't working, and I can't figure out why...
while the value of x and y is same,vscode and other online judge and compiler says no,but on codeblocks it says yes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, n, j;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    long long int a[n], x = 0, y = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    }

    for (i = n - 1, j = 1; i >= 0; i--, j = j * 10) {
        y = y + a[i] * j;
    }

    printf("%d ", y);

    for (i = 0, j = 1; i < n; i++, j = j * 10) {
        x = x + a[i] * j;
    }

    printf("%d ", x);

    if (x == y) {
        printf("YES");
    }
    else {
        printf("NO");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you told us what the code is supposed to do. Please also give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you have small problem in your code which is in this line:

```
scanf("%d",&a[i]);
```

the array called `a` is of type `long long int` and to scan any values into it, use :

```
scanf(" %lld",&a[i]);
```

where `%lld` means that you are scanning a `long long int` value, also there is a leading space before `%lld` to ignore leading spaces if any (not obligatory and has no use in this case but would be very useful when scanning `char`).

the second thing is that the supposed answer to be output is **NO** not **YES**.

this is due to the logic of your code, look how you calculate `x`:

```
for(i=0,j=1; i<n; i++,j=j*10)
{
    x=x+(a[i]*j);
}
```

`x` is calculated by concatenating integers from the array in the order from **a[0]** till **a[n-1]**

while in the loop for calculating the value for `y`:

```
for(i=n-1,j=1; i>=0; i--,j=j*10)
{
    y=y+(a[i]*j);
}
```

`y` is calculated by concatenating integers from the array in the order from **a[n-1]** till **a[0]**

which isn't the same for `x`.

to correct it, you can change the for loop of `y` to :

```
for(i=0,j=1; i<n; i++,j=j*10)
{
    y=y+(a[i]*j);
}
```

or you can modify the for loop for `x`.

this should solve your problem.

Comment: You say "also there is a leading space before `%lld` to avoid the reading of null character into the array where that null character resides in the buffer from the previous scanning".  It isn't clear where you think the null bytes are coming from, but that space simply skips white space (null bytes are not white space).  However, all the numeric conversion specifications always skip leading white space, so the space in the format string is harmless but unnecessary.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, you are right, thanks for clarifying, I edited the post.